# Can we add mediaboxes on shop page in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am trying to change shop page layout. I am trying to add mediaboxes on shop page in woocommerce.

Can we change layout of shop page in woocommerce??

Comment: Can I add all code in archive-product.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes. definitely. just add a folder named "woocommerce" to youe theme root and create a file named "archive-product.php" in that folder and add your own code there!

Comment: and also you can add all code in "archive-product.php"

Comment: Yes, you can see everything that you have written in that file at your shop page. but at first have a look at its default code and change or update that code based on your needs (if you want just have a customization on that)

in below link you can see default codes for that

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/archive-product.php